# 僕が強くならなきゃ　from 月の大きさ　song

Tags: i-adjectives, potential-form

I believe that it means `I have to become strong` but I don't really know how the grammar works in the sentence. I know it's using `強い`　and I guess `なる` in potencial form

Pleas explain to me how this works

Comment: ならなきゃ is a colloquial shorthand for ならなければならない which means "must get stronger" in this context.

Comment: here's info on なきゃ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/how-to-use-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8D%E3%82%83-correctly