# What does なきゃともがいてる mean in this context?

Tags: parsing, contractions, quotes

[image]

What kind of meaning does "なきゃともがいてる" convey in both of the sentences in one of the panel above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

- なきゃ＝なければ(ならない)  : must
- と makes a clause like と言う
- もがいている : is struggling

A simple way of understanding this would be to add '思って' after 'と'. Thus

- 生きなきゃともがいている = 生きなければならないと思ってもがいている

  struggling because he thinks he must live
- 前に進まなきゃともがいている

  struggling because he thinks he must go forward.

Another way is to take this construction as a mix of

- ・・・しようともがく: struggle / try hard to [do], and
- なきゃ  : 'must', adding the sense of duty or obligation

so the above sentences mean 'telling himself to live on' / 'trying to persuade himself to go forward'.

The both ways shouldn't make a lot of difference, but I suppose the latter is a better way to understand them (based on my understanding of the English version.)

**A side note:**

なきゃ does not always mean 'must'. See e.g. [this post.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/how-to-use-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8D%E3%82%83-correctly)
Unlike your example, such なきゃ (as in the title of the post) can be replaced only by なければ, and not by なければならない. (Both can replace なきゃ in your example)