# Difference between なきゃand なくちゃ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

i understand that they’re short forms of なければ and なくて but i don’t understand the different nuances between them. thanks!

ex.

勉強しなきゃ。
vs
勉強しなくちゃ。

Comment: i edited it, sorry! it was a typo!

Comment: Please note that なきゃ is a casual contraction of なければ (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010)), and なくちゃ is a casual contraction of なくては.