# Pitch accent of けりゃ/なきゃ

Tags: pitch-accent

Does it keep the pitch of its original form? So 食べ\なきゃ, 食べ\りゃ, 行かな\きゃ, 行かな\けりゃ etc or does it change?

Comment: What is the "original" form for 食べなきゃ? Is it 食べない or 食べる?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think it keeps the original pitch accent before the [eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12580/5010).

- あそぶ‾: あそばな\ければ あそばな\きゃ
- なく‾: なかな\ければ なかな\きゃ
- がんば\る: がんばら\なければ がんばら\なきゃ
- およ\ぐ: およが\なければ およが\なきゃ
- か\く: かか\なければ かか\なきゃ

- あかい‾: あか\ければ あか\けりゃ
- あお\い: あお\ければ あお\けりゃ
- お\おい: お\おければ お\おけきゃ
- こ\い: こ\ければ こ\けりゃ

Comment: Ok thank you!!!